# Setting localStorage using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, local-storage

I am creating a weather dashboard and am trying to save the city name to local storage. I already have the logic written to have the city post in the history section I just can't get the data to stay there after I reload the page. I have checked and it is saving to local storage but just not retrieving it. Here is the fetch call and the code underneath where I am trying to save the localStorage:

```
    fetch(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + searchCity + '&units=imperial&appid=64a50easdasdda68eb7a2b92c0bc02b65b123123121234593'
        )

        .then(function (response) {
            
            return response.json();
        })

        .then(function (data) {
            // localStorage.setItem(data.name, JSON.stringify(data));
            getCity(data);
            getTemp(data);
            getWS(data);
            getHumid(data)
            getForecast(data)
            getCityLast(data)
        })
    
}

function getCityLast(data) {
    var saveCity = data.name
    var saveCityDiv = document.createElement('button')
    
    saveCityDiv.classList.add('list-item')
    var saveCityText = document.createTextNode(saveCity)
    saveCityDiv.appendChild(saveCityText)
    getLastCity.appendChild(saveCityDiv)

    localStorage.setItem(data.name, JSON.stringify(data));

    console.log(localStorage.key(data))

    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i)

        getLastCity.saveCityDiv += `${key}`
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real API key. You shouldn't post it in a public forum.

Comment: What is `localStorage.key(data)` supposed to return? The argument to `localStorage.key()` should be an index, but `data` is an object.

Comment: ```getLastCity.saveCityDiv += `${key}` ``` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Use `localStorage.key(data.name) ` instead of `localStorage.key(data)`

Comment: @roa That's wrong too. The argument has to be an integer.

Comment: If you're trying to add the key to the DIV, it should be `saveCityDiv.innerText += key;`

Comment: It is not my real key. Just filler. And changing the code to your last comment didn't work. It is currently storing properly, just the retrieval is broken. Any other recommendations? @Barmar

Comment: Where are you retrieving the data?

Comment: Another dev told me to use that for loop to store the data on the page. I don't know if it is correct but that is what he told me to put and I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve your persisted stringified JSON data, you want to do this:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i)
        const data = localStorage.getItem(key)
        console.log(`${key} - ${data}`)
    }
```

Comment: I created a new function at the bottom called on load. I was able to get it working off of this code. Thanks!